# EntityManager is always null

Tags: java, jpa

I'm getting null always and I don't know why. I am exhausted of looking for the solution but a I couldn't find it. I am working with Spring 5.0.1 trying to inject with jpa, so I will put part of the code.

Persistence.xml (in META-INF directory)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<!-- para que reconozca los Servicios, DAOs, etc anotados -->
<!--<context:component-scan base-package="ttps.daosjpa" /> -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="Controlador,DAO,Modelo" />

<!-- propiedades de la Base de Datos 
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />-->

<!-- DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
     <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/ttps2017" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="2" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600 " /> 
</bean>


<!-- Configuración JPA -->
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- <property name="packagesToScan" value="ttps.springmvc.entities" /> --> 
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="Controlador,DAO,Modelo" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<!-- Manejador de Transacciones -->

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager ">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

this is my genericDAOHibernate ...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
@Transactional
public class GenericDAOHibernate<T> implements GenericDAO<T> {

    private Class<T> PersistentClass;
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.entityManager= em;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return this.entityManager;
    }


    public GenericDAOHibernate(Class<T> entidad) {
        this.PersistentClass = entidad;
    }

    @Override
    public T persistir(T entity) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(this.getEntityManager());
        System.out.println("");
        this.getEntityManager().persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

And this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/META-INF/newPersistence.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Configuration for the DispatcherServlet
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here should be dots instead of commas.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="Controlador.DAO.Modelo" />
```

Comment: Yes, I changed it after the post but I think that is no part of the problem. I think there is something referred to the xml's because there is no "error" in the code according to eclipse. Thanks for you asnwer!